# Reading values from a dynamic table form

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, visual-studio

OK. So I am assisting my backend developer with some form submission issues. Here's the scenario :

There is a table inside a `html form` with two columns and dynamic rows. The user can click on an *Add* button to insert a row with one text input for each column. I did that using `jQuery`. Here's how the table looks after the user has inserted two rows :

```
<form>
...
<tbody class="table-hover addScreen">
  <tr>
    <td class="text-left"> <input name="screenNameTextBox" type="text" id="screenNameTextBox" value="a"> </td>
    <td class="text-left"> <input name="seatsAvlTextBox" type="text" id="seatsAvlTextBox" value="b"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-left"> <input name="screenNameTextBox" type="text" id="screenNameTextBox" value="c"> </td>
    <td class="text-left"> <input name="seatsAvlTextBox" type="text" id="seatsAvlTextBox" value="d"> </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
...
</form>
```

Now we have no idea how to read this data on the server side when the `submit` button is clicked. We tried this :

```
string textboxval1 = screenNameTextBox.value;
string textboxval2 = seatsAvlTextBox.Value;
```

but that only gives us the first set of values. Please suggest what are the best practices when doing something like this.

*PS : I'm an iOS dev so forgive me if i said some blunder. ;-)*

Comment: id's should be unique in a document, use classes instead and use a loop to read the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick example of my comment,

```js
function readForm(){
 event.preventDefault;
var resultsBox= document.getElementById('results');
   
  var screenNames=document.getElementsByClassName('screenNameTextBox');
  var seatsAv=document.getElementsByClassName('seatsAvlTextBox');
  
  for(var i=0;i<=screenNames.length;i++){
    
   resultsBox.innerHTML+=screenNames[i].value+' '+seatsAv[i].value+'<br>';
   
    
    }
  
  
  
  
  }
```

```html
<form onsubmit="readForm();">
  Enter some values:<br>
  <input  type="text" class="screenNameTextBox"/>
   <input  type="text" class="seatsAvlTextBox"/>
  <input  type="text" class="screenNameTextBox"/>
   <input  type="text" class="seatsAvlTextBox"/>
  
  <input type="submit" />
 </form>
<div id="results">results  :<br></div>
```